# Get real size of custom keyboard area in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am trying to make some custom keyboard using swift ui. I faced some problem. I cannot check real size of area custom keyboard is showing. Below is some capture.

[image: custom keyboard in portrait]

The area where I want to check its size is in blue square. It depends on swift view I made. So I made some logic entire size is related with screen size.

[image: custom keyboard in landscape]

The problem is occurred in this situation. As you can see, in landscape mode, some additional space exists. Blue square is not fulfill screen. For calculating size better, need to get size of that extra space.

If you have a nice way to get it, please answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updated at 2024. 4. 3

This is log when rotate landscape to portrait

```
viewLayoutMarginsDidChange Optional((0.0, 0.0, 430.0, 107.66666666666666))
viewLayoutMarginsDidChange Optional((0.0, 0.0, 430.0, 107.66666666666666))
viewLayoutMarginsDidChange Optional((0.0, 0.0, 430.0, 107.66666666666666))
viewLayoutMarginsDidChange Optional((0.0, 0.0, 430.0, 107.66666666666666))
viewWillAppear Optional((0.0, 0.0, 932.0, 430.0))
viewDidAppear Optional((0.0, 0.0, 698.0, 212.66666666666666))
```

viewLayoutMarginsDidChange : during lotation
viewWillAppear : before keyboard will be showing
viewDidAppear : after keyboard did showed

Device size is 932, 430. (I used 15 pro max simulator)

So you want device size on keyboard extension, check it on UIInputViewController viewWillAppear. (And you can calculate device orientation with this.)

If you want to get actual keyboard area, check it on UIInputViewController viewDidAppear. (on landscape, there is a space on left and right. So its width reduces)

---

Previous Answer at 2023. 5. 4

My previous self answer was wrong so I delete it and write again.

Keyboard is app extension so cannot get real size in swift ui. Should get in input view controller.

Use layoutMarginsGuide to get area size.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
    if let size = self.inputView?.layoutMarginsGuide.layoutFrame.size {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Send this value to swift view then you can calculate with it.

My example result

[image]